# React native call functions and change states from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I currently have a function that renders a component `NewButton`, in that component, how do I call the function `toggleModalVisibility`, which is defined outside of that component? That function will change many states and call other functions, and change rendering as well.

```
import React, {  useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Button, View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput,ScrollView, Modal} from 'react-native'
import { BottomSheet } from 'react-native-btr';
import NewButton from './NewButton'


export default function CardFolder({navigation, navigation: {setOptions}}){

    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    //many other states
 
    const toggleModalVisibility = () => {
        //changes states, calls other functions, change rendering, Toggle bottomSheet
    };

    return(
        < >
        <Modal> modal containing a text field, change states </Modal>
        <BottomSheet>contains other options, upload something to db</BottomSheet>
        <View style = {{flex:1}}>

        <NewButton style = {{bottom: 50}} />

        </View>
        </>  
    )      
}
```

The Component:

```
import {View, Button} from 'react-native'

export default class NewButton extends React.Component {
 
        return(
            <View style = {[styles.container,this.props.style]}>
                //how do I call the functon toggleModalVisibility here?
                <Button onPress={toggleModalVisibility}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add it as a prop to NewButton Component

```
<NewButton style={{bottom: 50}} toggleModalVisibility={toggleModalVisibility} />
```

and the call it like

```
<Button onPress={this.props.toggleModalVisibility}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As @Krosf suggested you, you should pass the function by props and then call the function when Button is pressed, in your case you are using class component, so you should use the "**this**" keyword in order to access your "**NewButton props**"

***like this:***

```
<Button onPress={ this.props.toggleModalVisibility } />
```